# The IF condition is true but the program execute the else

Tags: android

There is my code that controll a webView, the string "webSiteUrl" contain the name of the my website homepage. If the user press the back button when the homepage is opened the application will close, else the webview have to load the homepage but thought on the webview is loaded the homepage, the application execute the else condition. How can I solve this problem?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    String string = webView.getUrl();
    if (string == webSiteUrl) {
        finishAffinity();
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        webView.loadUrl(webSiteUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: If program executes else then if is false. And if you output compared values you will see why.

Comment: print WebsiteUrl & string to console and post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare `String` using `.equals()` so

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    String string = webView.getUrl();
    if (string.equals(webSiteUrl)) {
        finishAffinity();
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        webView.loadUrl(webSiteUrl);
    }
}
```